# PHP Combine multiple arrays of objects and change array structure

Tags: php, arrays

I have multiple separate arrays of objects that are imported (JSON-encoded) from MySQL that I need to merge and change structure. I basically need the combined [time] and [day] entries to be an array of [cycle] so I can loop over them. Currently after import/decoding the array of objects structure for each MySQL query looks like this:

**(query 1)**

```
 stdClass Object
 (
 [day] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [day] => 1
                [time] => 60
                [name] => Running
                [cycle] => 1
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [day] => 5
                [time] => 30
                [name] => Running
                [cycle] => 1
            )

    )

[id] => 15359593
  )
```

**(query 2)**

```
stdClass Object
  (
[day] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [day] => 1
                [time] => 55
                [name] => Running
                [cycle] => 2
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [day] => 5
                [time] => 15
                [name] => Running
                [cycle] => 2
            )

    )

[id] => 36848901
 )
```

The structure that need is:

```
stdClass Object
(
[day] => 1
[name] => Running
[cycle] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [time] => 60
                [cycle] => 1
                [day] => 1
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [time] => 55
                [cycle] => 2
                [day] => 1
            )
    )
[id] => 36848901
)

stdClass Object
(
[day] => 5
[name] => Running
[cycle] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [time] => 30
                [cycle] => 1
                [day] => 5
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [time] => 15
                [cycle] => 2
                [day] => 5
            )
    )
 [id] => 1237465
 )
```

I need the program to then iterate over the array using foreach [day] and then [cycle] to produce something like this:

```
 name       day       cycle 1     cycle 2      cycle ..
 Running    1         60          55           ..
 Running    5         30          15           ..
 ..
```

It can only do it on a row by row basis. I don't have (much) control over this part of the process.

I have tried changing the structure by using foreach loops and array commands like this:

```
 $newArray[] = array( "name" => $this->name, "day" => $this->day, 
 array("cycle" => $this->cycle, array("time" => $this->time, "cycle" => 
 $this->cycle, "day" => $this->day)));
```

This gives me a structure that is almost right, per entry but not combined for all. 
To combine them I've tried array_merge_recursive() and various variants but no luck.

So what I think I need is to merge the arrays of objects and then change the structure to have the values of each [time] and [day] to be nested inside the [cycle] so I can loop over them.

What is the best way to do this?

It is running on PHP 7.2.

More of my attempted code:

```
// get {data} part of JSON-encoded field for each mysql result
for ($x = 0; $x < $this->cycleCount; $x++) {
    preg_match("/{.*}/",$this->tmpString[$x]['data'],$matches);
    $this->data[$x] = json_decode($matches[0]);

    foreach ($this->data[$x] as $day) {
        $newArray[] = array( "name" => $day->name, "day" => $day->day, 
                         array("cycle" => $day->cycle, 
                            array("time" => $day->time, 
                                  "cycle" => $day->cycle, 
                                  "day" => $day->day)
                          )
                      );
    }
```

Comment: If you post a bit more of your attempted code, we can probably suggest a quick fix.

Comment: Is there any possibility to modify the query to get the data you want, in the order you want it?

Comment: @Nic3500 unfortunately not, there is multiple [day] & [name] data in a JSON-encoded field, with one [cycle] in the same field. Every new cycle is a separate mysql results row

Comment: @Nic3500 It is also not just a case of the order of the data but also of combining it with other queries to get the array that I need

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array();
$object = json_decode($querObject,true);

foreach($object as $day => $info)
{
    foreach($info['cycle'] as $cycleInfo)
   {
        $data[$info['$id']]['name'] = $cycleInfo['name'];
        $data[$info['$id']]['day'] = $cycleInfo['day'];
        $data[$info['$id']]['id'] = $cycleInfo['id'];
        $data[$info['$id']]['cycle'][] =array('time'=>$cycleInfo['time'],'cycle'=>$cycleInfo['cycle'],'day'=>=>$cycleInfo['day']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggested solution. As it stands the solution does not work for me: it never gets into the foreach($info['cycle'] as $cycleInfo) loop. When the foreach loop line is removed and just the $data[$info]['id']]... part remains I get an empty structure.

Comment: In the array of objects structure that is generated in my original code cycle is a string: [cycle] => 1 which means that in the suggested solution $info['cycle'] is also  string, so foreach won't work